# Meteor: Possible to reference a local package while writing a local package?

Tags: meteor

I have a local package that I am writing. I wanted to extend some functionality from a few of the core meteor packages. In order to do this, I was creating another local package.

So now local package A is attempting to use local package B. But even after adding the symlink to package A's packages folder, I get an `unknown package` error when running test-packages.

`meteor add local-package-b`

Doesn't work because meteor complains: `You're not in a Meteor project directory`

Is this even possible or do I need to publish to atmosphere first? I wanted to keep the additional package local as it's going to be a handful of helper methods.

I've double checked the name in package B's package.js file and it matches with my api.use in package A's package.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinks shouldn't be necessary here. Local packages are found by checking:

1. Anything under the directory pointed to by the environment variable `PACKAGE_DIRS`.
2. Anything under the `packages` directory in the current application directory.
3. Core packages.

As long as your two packages reside in one of those three locations, the should be found. Also see my article on [local packaes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages) for more details on (1).

---

Based on our conversation below, the main issue had to do with the approach to creating a new package. While it's being written, it's necessary that a package be added to (or tested by) an app. Here are the steps I take when working on a shared, local package:

1. Create a new app.
2. `meteor create --package mypackage`
3. `meteor add mypackage`
4. Finish writing and testing the package.
5. Move `mypackage` under my `PACKAGE_DIRS` directory so it will be available to other apps.

Comment: I think the problem might be related to the fact that I'm building a package, not an app. So when I attempt to reference another local package, it's unable to find it. Following the same steps within a meteor application works. But when attempting to do this in another local package, I get the errors described in the question.

Comment: I see. The way I like to develop our local packages is by creating an empty app and then doing `meteor create --package [packagename]`. I then develop the package under the `packages` directory. This lets me quickly modify and test it. When it's done, I move it into my `PACKAGE_DIRS` directory and add it to our local packages repository.

Comment: I just tried this out really quickly by creating a standard meteor app and then 2 local packages inside of it. I am able to reference 1 local package from the other without any issues. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't know if you want to add an additional answer based on your comments that I can accept? It fits more closely to the scenario as it's about being able to leverage a local package from another local package, not a meteor app. 

It still feels like a work around having to create packages in an app, but I'll definitely take it. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer based on our discussion - hopefully others will find that helpful.