# making common packages for several meteor projects

Tags: meteor, package

I am trying to build three different applications in meteor for different roles.

Currently, my approach is to create three different applications, and each application's server has a symbolic link to a folder with the name 'server'. So far it works fine for all the packages that are dependent on client. But for packages, that uses server, I have to add the packages to all the projects.

So is there any anyway where I can keep one common folder whose package is gonna be shared with all projects without individually adding packages to each projects.

Comment: Also see [Possible to reference a local package while writing a local package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363616/meteor-possible-to-reference-a-local-package-while-writing-a-local-package). Basically you need one directory with packages in it that you can reference via `PACKAGE_DIRS`. Note the contents of that directory can be one repo or multiple - it's up to you.

Comment: Please have a look at my approach and guide me why it is not working. I have created two projects A and B. Project A is using the package slingshot  on the server side. Now I am making a folder called 'server' and both the projects point to them through symbolic link. But project B gives an error saying 'Slingshot not defined'. So how can I put this package in one folder and allow both A and B to use them